# iOS Unit Test won't build

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unit-testing

I have some unit tests in my application that used to run and pass perfectly fine in a copy of my main target. Now suddenly, I cannot seem to run them at all, the build fails. It keeps coming up with the error:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: 
   "MyApp.isoFormatter.unsafeMutableAddressor: MyApp.DateFormatter", 
   referenced from: MyAppTests.appTests.testAllDayISO () -> () in appTests.o
```

There is also the warning:

```
Auto-Linking supplied 'Pods/Google/Frameworks/GGLAnalytics.framework/GGLAnalytics', 
framework linker option at Pods/Google/Frameworks/GGLAnalytics.framework/GGLAnalytics is not a dylib
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening now?

Comment: Did you try clean up the project and remove DerivedData and then run test again?

Comment: Yeah I tried that. I have two targets for my application, when I change the host application for the test target to the original one it seems to work fine.

Comment: This looks like a simulator build (x86_64).  Is that intended?

Comment: @PhillipMills Yeah I have tried it with both a simulator and real device and still run into the same issues. It seems to work fine when I change the host application to the original target but I specifically want the new target to be for running tests